# Is the word “key” of the sentence an uncountable noun or an adjective?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

> The diplomat was quick to organize a peaceful dialogue between the two countries’ leaders, and many say that his efforts were **key** to averting a war.

I am not sure whether the word “key” is an uncountable noun or an adjective. And, I also think about the sentence is typo, the sentence has to add “a” or “the” before “key”.

Please tell me your thought.

The sentence is from “EIKEN 1 kyu deruzyun de saitan goukaku goi mondai kanzen seiha” page 38.

Comment: Sans article it's an adjective.  With an article it's a noun.

Comment: @HotLicks I'm in the process of writing an answer that says that (but rather longer-windedly).

Comment: @WillCrawford - I get short of breath easily.

Comment: @HotLicks almost passed out stifling my laughter :) (please) feel free to edit, I fear I've rambled a bit

Comment: See also ['is key' or  is the key'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33203/is-key-or-is-the-key). The extended expression  'be key to' meaning 'be the controlling factor in' / 'be imperative in' is harder to find.

Comment: My own view is that, here, 'key' is a noun with the zero article.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I think "is key to" is also easier to explain, since it's usually "the key to understanding …" which is a fairly straightforward metaphorical usage (via "…opens the door to…").

Comment: @Nigel J Modelling on 'is crucial to' indicates an adjectival usage, but doubtless there are different models. My view is that it's pointless analysing 'is key to' except as an idiom.

Comment: Please take this to [chat] guys?!

Answer (score 3):

It's slightly unclear what your actual question is, but presuming it to be "is this correct?" then the answer is "yes".

In this case *key* is being used as an adjective, and the meaning of it is that this action was *pivotal* (one can also say it was *a turning point*): had it failed, events would have taken a different course, and likely war would have broken out soon afterwards.

As @HotLicks has just commented, the presence or absence of an article simply switches *key* between acting as a noun or an adjective, and the meaning is pretty much unchanged. The only difference depends on whether the article is definite or indefinite: *the key* implies that that single thing (action or event) was both necessary and sufficient; *a key* means that some other actions or events were needed.

Comment: Dear, Will Crawford. Thank you for your explanation, I understand that in this case the word “key” is an adjective not a noun. I also very helpful your alternative sentence, that starts “Had it failed, “. Thank you very much.

Comment: FWIW, Taka, the linked "duplicate" question is actually full of good answers. The use of the word "crucial" there is exactly synonymous with "pivotal" in my answer. It *is* a different question though.

Comment: Dear, Will Crawford. Thank your for your another information, I will search the words “crucial” and “pivotal”. And, I did not know an abbreviation, FWIW. I looked up the abbreviation. The meaning is “for what it is worth” or “(sonna hanashi mo aruto) hanashi wo sonomamani uketoru in Japanese.

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably should not have used the abbreviation!